# Find a number to the power of another number?

Tags: java, math, computer-science, exponent

I am trying to write a function in java that finds the result of an operand raised to the power of another.

I **can't use the pow function** or any form of loop. What are any possible solutions? I tried "^" and that didn't work.

```
public static String raiseP(int op1, int op2){
    int result  = op1 ^ op2;  //Doesn't Work
    return result; 
}
```

Would there be a way to do this using basic math?

I have written:

```
public static int pow(int x, int y, int n, int z){
  if (y == n){
      System.out.println(z);
      return z;
  }
  else{
      z = z*x;
      n += 1;
      pow(x,y,n,z);
      return 0;      
  }

}
ex: pow(5,9,0,1) == 5^9
```

but am not allowed to use recursion.

Comment: Are you allowed to use recursive functions?

Comment: please show what you've tried within your post.

Comment: if you can't use any form of loops or `Math.pow` then the only other option is recursion?

Comment: Use a really long series of `if...elses`. Or a really long `switch...case` without breaks. Or how about you show what you tried to not get any more ridiculous suggestions from me.

Comment: Sorry, I just added some clarification. This is kinda new to me.

Comment: `^` is an XOR logical operator, not a "to the power of".

Comment: Look up [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: This will actually help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182314/recursive-exponent-method if you dig up a little harder :)

Comment: @AntonH Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working)

Comment: another duplicate: [Raising a number to a power in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8842504/995714)

Comment: So, no recursion, no loop, no function call? I don't think it is even possible to calculate power without them.

Comment: @JoesphRoberts with what I said, yes, but it has its limitations, and is an absolutely terrible idea. If you can't use recursion, loops or `pow`, I don't see any other way than what 'dasblinkenlight' suggested.

Comment: You could also technically hard-copy all the possible combinations in a huge 2D array and just use the function as a lookup into the array, but again, terrible idea.

Comment: You can compute `pow(2, n)` with `1 << n` but somehow I doubt this is what your assignment is asking for.

Comment: With those restrictions, they probably are leading you to use recursion as a means of looping.

Comment: This is impossible. It's like saying Take photographs of invisible objects.

Answer (score 3):

Without being able to call Math.pow or using loops, the only other possibility is using recursion:

```
public int powerFunction(int base, int exponent) {
    if(exponent < 0){ throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported negative pow");  }
    if(exponent == 0){ return 1; } 
    else{
        return base * powerFunction(base, exponent - 1);
    }
}
```

Calling `powerFunction(2, 3)` will give you: 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 8

Comment: Please don't solve people's homework for them. A good hint is fine, even a link to an algorithm, but providing an outright implementation is usually a disservice to them. Besides, this approach is not ideal, because passing a very high exponent has a potential of overflowing the stack.

Comment: The limitation with this is the assumption that the exponent is a positive integer. Still +1

Comment: Yeah, a check for positive exponents is required. 
`if (exponent < 0) throw something`.

Comment: Base should be a double

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use that

```
pow(x,y) = exp(y*log(x))
```

which is also part of the implementation of the power function in the math library.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion could help you:

```
public static int myPowerRec(int op1, int op2, int res) {
  if (op2 == 0) {
    return res;
  }
  else {
    return (myPowerRec(op1, op2 - 1, op1 * res));
  }
}
```

You will need to initialize res to 1 (`myPowerRec(23, 2, 1)` will give you `1 * 23 * 23`). 
This recursion is called [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and will allow you to use this function without stack problem.

Be careful, you must check `op2` value before.

Comment: this is pretty good but does java support Tail Call Optimization ?

Comment: Indeed I didn't check, Java isn't my main language.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop:

```
public static int power(a, b) { // a ^ b
  int p = 1;
  for (int i = 1, i <= b; i++)
    p *= a;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: I can't use loops